# Using "because" at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: conjunctions, parts-of-speech

In Standard English, the word *because* can be used to introduce a clause (subordinating conjunction) or paired with *of* to form a compound preposition. Recently, *because* has been used in non-standard English to introduce a noun phrase (because noun), as such, behaves like a preposition.
*source: https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/because-as-a-preposition*

---

Subordinating conjunction

> Jack got a raise because he did a good job.

Compound preposition

> Jack got a raise because of his good performance.

Because noun

> Jack got a raise, because efficiency.

(Adding a bit of emphasis on *because* and a pause - half a beat, almost like stopping before a comma, before the word efficiency)

---

Consider the following sentence.

*Because Jack does the job so well, he can expect a raise.*

Following Standard English, is the *because* in the sentence above considered a subordinating conjunction despite sentence order?

Comment: "Jack got a raise, because efficiency." is incorrect. Rather "Jack got a raise, because (of his) efficiency."

Comment: It is non-standard and considered a preposition when introducing a noun phrase. source: https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/because-as-a-preposition

Comment: Adding a reference for this kind of usage to your question would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, no. The word **because** loses its status as a subordinating conjunction because it is no longer acting to join a dependant clause with an independent clause.

However, the dependent clause that it is part of remains a subordinating clause. Also, this clause, with **because**, becomes an introductory phrase.

---

Mignon Fogarty talks about starting a sentence with **because** in ["Can You Start a Sentence with 'Because'?"](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/can-you-start-a-sentence-with-because):

> "Because" heads up subordinate clauses, which means if you have a clause that starts with "because," you must also have a main clause in your sentence. A main clause is something that could be a complete sentence by itself. The main clause can come first or last; if it comes last, you need a comma.
>
> Because Squiggly woke up late, he had to postpone the fishing trip.
>   (subordinate clause first, note the comma)

Answer (score 0):

"Because" is always a preposition but it can take various kinds of complement:

i. Content clause complement: "Jack got a raise because he  did a good job."

ii. Prepositional phrase complement: "Jack got a raise because of his good performance"

iii. And a noun phrase (marginally acceptable): "Jack got a raise, because efficiency"

The sentence order doesn't make any difference; mobility is a basic trait of constituency.